# ext_conf_template - how to use settings in root.ts

Tags: typo3

I develop TYPO3 extension. And I have file ext_conf_templates with my settings. How do I use this settings in the typoscript, root.ts ?

```
# cat=Template_einstellung/101/0104; type=options[nein=,ja=noborder]; label=remove bottom border (only with transparent use)
template.border =
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ext_localconf.php` add below code.

```
$conf = unserialize($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf'][$_EXTKEY]);
$border = $conf['template.']['border'];
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptConstants("
plugin.tx_yourextensionkey.template.border = $border
");
```

Now, anywhere in your typoscript setup you can access your border variable with {$plugin.tx_yourextensionkey.template.border}. You can name this variable as you like but best practice is to use plugin and extension name prefix to make it unique across installations.

Above works for TYPO3 CMS version 8.7. I think it´s the same routine all the way down to version 6.2 but I´m not 100% sure.

You can verify that this works with the `Template` backend module. In the main select box select `TypoScript Object Browser`. Make sure that the browser select box says `Constants`. Now you should be able to find your new variable.

[image]